Sending emails without custom DNS validation
We are moving the infrastructure over for our corporate client system to AWS; however at the moment, we send emails through sendmail on our servers, and only have an SPF record with each client set up.
I understand you can no longer send an email through sendmail on EC2 servers, and I don't want to have to set up an identity for each domain when using SES if I can avoid it, as there are loads of them, and I will need each clients IT department to set it up.
What alternatives are there? I have looked by can't find a 3rd party to use that would allow set up with just an SPF record.
Any help with how this should be set up please let me know, ideally we would continue to use mail within our PHP send script.
Any 3rd party integration would need to be one we can connect to through PHP.

"I understand you can no longer send an email through sendmail on EC2 servers" - what makes you say that? I've not tried sendmail but postfix is working fine for me. And are you really sending emails directly from the MTA on your application host????

We sure are! and have got an excellent sender score. To be fair we have been doing it for 20 years in this method. But now we need to modernise and update, it is a pain though moving a load of clients and getting their IT teams etc to set up DNS entries for each identity.
